# What is the difference between AC Delco Spark Plug 41-808 and 41-905?

Tags: chevrolet, sparkplugs

I have a 1989 IROC-Z  carbureted engine with aluminum heads.  It has one of the original ZZZ 350 crate engines ([bottom of page 6](http://www.hsv-gts.ls2.com/gm_performance_parts_catalog_2008.pdf)).  The block is the same as the OEM engine. The internal parts (rods) crank up-beat which makes this car stout and fast.

It is time to replace the spark plugs. I understand iridium may be too hot for the aluminum heads.

I am considering the AC Delco 19307140 ([aka the 41-808](http://www.oscaroparts.com/acdelco-spark-plug-41-808-6000526-7212-p)) and the 19301809 ([aka the 41-905](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/detail/ACD2/41905/03435.oap?year=1974&make=Checker&model=Taxicab&vi=1499856&ck=Search_03435_1499856_-1&pt=03435&ppt=C0334)). I am leaning toward the 41-905 plug.

- 41-808 gap = .047"
- 41-808 reach = .75"
- 41-905 gap = .035"
- 41-905 reach = .43"

Would the AC Delco 41-905 sparkplug work well in my engine?

Comment: Which plugs are in there now?

Comment: How are iridium pugs to hot for aluminum heads?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the original plug for that engine is the FR5LS.
Source: http://www.corvetteforum.com/forums/c1-and-c2-corvettes/1059523-zz2-3-4-crate-engine-spark-plugs.html

FR5LS @ O'Reily Auto Parts: 
http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/detail/ACD0/FR5LS.oap?ck=Search_431_-1_-1&keyword=431&doInterchangeSearch=true

Gap (In): 0.035 Inch
Thread Reach (In): 0.750 Inch

I would go for a plug with the same reach as your current plug.